# Please advise which books are about strategy with explanations

Tags: strategy, learning, theory, positional-play

I have many books that show openings, endplays, tactics, different puzzle to find best moves, databases with games, articles...
All this stuff shows specific moves, which I have to find by myself.
I understand that this is supposed to increase my logic skill, but it is a very long and unproductive way. My life will not be enough to figure everything out on my own.

And I would like to learn something else. I want to know what the strategy might be. For example, how do I know which position is strong and why? What are the signs of strength? What positions should be avoided? What actions should I take to create a weakness in my opponent's position? What to pay attention to?

I am looking for a clear explanation of chess strategies. **Are there such books that would directly tell about possible strategies of action?** I feel like I don't know exactly what to think about in order to win.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to out community! You can take a look at the linked questions and please give us more info if you can't find what you're looking for there.

Comment: I'm not sure what your rating is, but _Winning Chess Strategies_ by Yasser Seirawan & Jeremy Silman is a very good beginner strategy book. [Good review of it by the Perpetual Chess Podcast](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/new-blog/2020/10/24/book-recap-talking-winning-chess-strategies-with-neal-bruce).